# Is there any way to collpase dynamically created rowsin vf pages

Tags: apex, visualforce, bootstrap

Below is vf page where i am creating rows dynamic. I want to collapse and expand each rows independently.

How can i achieve tht. I want to collapse from

1- Contact
2 - contact and like this each rows

[image]

vf page -

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="accountcontactwrapperclass" showHeader="false">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

    <apex:form >

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading backgroundTheme" style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold">Account</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <apex:outputPanel id="accountname">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <h5>
                                <div class="field_label " id="closedate">Account Name</div>
                            </h5>
                            <div>
                                <apex:inputField value="{!acc.Name}" label="CloseDate" styleClass="form-control"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <apex:outputPanel id="panelId">
                        <div class="panel panel-default" id="subs">
                            <div class="panel-heading backgroundTheme" style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold">Contact</div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <apex:variable var="count" value="{!1}"/>
                                <apex:repeat value="{!contactWrapperlist}" var="wrappers">
                                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading backgroundTheme" style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold">{!count} - Contact
                                                                                </div>

                                    <div class="row" id="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <apex:outputLabel style="margin-bottom: 0px;font-weight: inherit;" >Last Name</apex:outputLabel>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <apex:inputText value="{!wrappers.c.LastName}"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel panel-default" id="subs1">
                                        <div class="panel-heading backgroundTheme" style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold">Contact Email</div>
                                        <div class="panel-body" >
                                            <apex:repeat value="{!wrappers.contactEmails}" var="wrappers1">
                                                <div class="panel panel-default" id="subs">
                                                    <div class="panel-heading backgroundTheme" style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold">Contact Email</div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                                        <apex:outputLabel style="margin-bottom: 0px;font-weight: inherit;" >Email</apex:outputLabel>
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <apex:inputText value="{!wrappers1.c1.Email}"/>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                                        <apex:outputLabel style="margin-bottom: 0px;font-weight: inherit;" >Phone</apex:outputLabel>
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <apex:inputText value="{!wrappers1.c1.Phone}"/>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                </div>
                                                <apex:variable var="count" value="{!count + 1}"/>
                                            </apex:repeat>
                                            <div class="col-md-1" style="margin-top: 1.5em;">
                                                <apex:commandbutton value="Add Contact Email" action="{!addContactEmail}" reRender="panelId">
                                                    <apex:param name="wrapperId" value="{!wrappers.wrapperId}" assignTo="{!wrapperId}" />
                                                </apex:commandbutton>
                                            </div> 
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                   </div>                      
                                </apex:repeat>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:outputPanel>
                <apex:commandbutton value="Add Contact" action="{!addContact}" reRender="panelId"></apex:commandbutton>
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!SaveAll}"></apex:commandButton>
            </div>
        </div>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

apex class -

```
public class accountcontactwrapperclass {

    public Account acc {get;set;}
    public List<ContactEmail> contactEmaillist {get;set;}
    public List<ContactWrapper> contactWrapperlist {get;set;}
    public List<AccountWrapper> accountWrapperlist {get;set;}
    public List<Contact> cList;
    public List<Subscription_Offer__c> subsList;
    public List<Attachment> attachlist;
    public String wrapperId {get; set;}

    public accountcontactwrapperclass (ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        contactEmaillist = new List<ContactEmail>();
        contactWrapperlist = new List<ContactWrapper>();
        accountWrapperlist = new List<AccountWrapper>();
        acc = new Account();
        cList = new List<Contact>();
        subsList = new List<Subscription_Offer__c>();
        attachlist = new List<Attachment>();
        system.debug('@@@@@'+ contactWrapperlist);
        addContact();

    }

    public PageReference SaveAll(){ 
        upsert acc; 
        for(integer i=0;i<contactWrapperlist.size();i++){

            system.debug('contactWrapperlist.size()' + contactWrapperlist);
          ContactWrapper contwrapper = contactWrapperlist[i];
            List<ContactEmail> contEmails = new List<ContactEmail>();   
               contEmails =  contwrapper.contactEmails;
            For(ContactEmail cEmails: contEmails){
                Contact c = new Contact();
                c.accountId = acc.Id;
                //c.LastName = contwrapper.lastname;
                c.LastName = contwrapper.c.LastName;
              /*  c.Email = cEmails.Email;
                c.Phone = cEmails.Phone;*/
                c.Email = cEmails.c1.Email;
                c.Phone = cEmails.c1.Phone;
                //insert c;
                cList.add(c);



                //insert subsList;


               // system.debug('@@@@' + attachlist);

            }
        }
        insert cList;
        Map<String,Contact> contMapinsert = new Map<String,Contact>();

        for(Contact c1: cList){
           // contMapinsert.put(c1.Id,c1);
            Subscription_Offer__c subsoffer = new Subscription_Offer__c();
            subsoffer.Name = c1.LastName;
            subsoffer.Bill_To__c = c1.id;
            subsList.add(subsoffer);
        }
        upsert subsList;

        system.debug('clist' + cList);
        system.debug('subsList' + subsList);
        system.debug('attachlist' + attachlist);



        for(Subscription_Offer__c s:subsList){
           PageReference pdf = Page.subsofferaspdf;
                pdf.getParameters().put('id',s.id);
                Attachment attach = new Attachment();
                Blob body;
                try {
                    body = pdf.getContent();
                }catch (VisualforceException e) {
                    body = Blob.valueOf('Some Text');
                }
                attach.Body = body;
                attach.Name = s.Name;
                attach.IsPrivate = false;
                attach.ParentId = s.id;
                attachlist.add(attach);
        }

        insert attachlist;
        return null;
    }

    public void addContact(){

        ContactWrapper contWrap = new ContactWrapper();
        ContactEmail contactEmailwrap = new ContactEmail();

        contWrap.contactEmails.add(contactEmailwrap);
        contactWrapperlist.add(contWrap);
        //contactEmaillist.add(contactEmailwrap);

    }

    public void addContactEmail(){
        for(ContactWrapper s : contactWrapperlist){
            system.debug('@@@@' + contactWrapperlist);
            if(s.wrapperId == wrapperId){
                 s.contactEmails.add(new ContactEmail());
            }   
        } 
    }


    public class ContactEmail{        
        public String Phone {get;set;}
        public String Email {get;set;}
        public Contact c1 {get;set;}
        public ContactEmail()
        {
            c1 = new Contact();
        }
    }

    public class ContactWrapper{
        public String lastname {get;set;}
        public Contact c {get;set;}
        public string wrapperId {get;set;}
        public List<ContactEmail> contactEmails {get;set;}
        public ContactWrapper(){
            Blob b = Crypto.GenerateAESKey(128);
            String h = EncodingUtil.ConvertTohex(b);
            wrapperId = h.SubString(0,8)+ '-' + h.SubString(8,12) + '-' + h.SubString(12,16) + '-' + h.SubString(16,20) + '-' + h.substring(20);
            contactEmails = new List<ContactEmail>();
            c = new Contact();
        }
        //= new List<ContactEmail>();
    }

    public class AccountWrapper{       
        public String accountName {get;set;}
        public List<ContactWrapper> contactWrapper = new List<ContactWrapper>();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function collapseChildren( listItem ){

        j$( '.' + listItem ).children().toggle( 500 );
    }
```

you could add a class to the top level row that you want to use and use jQuery to collapse them by toggling the rows, pass the class name to the above method onclick. here is a fiddle: [Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/rpp0527/m7n0mt0r/)

Comment: Hi Ronnie.. Can i keep it collapse by default.. On click i need to expand else it will remain collpase..

Comment: should be able to onload call the toggle method

Comment: any chnages in your script needed in Fiddle..

Comment: I've updated the fiddle with another way that is likely a prettier option: https://jsfiddle.net/rpp0527/m7n0mt0r/3/